# Concistency issue when writing data on different location within the same cache-line?

Tags: caching, architecture

When multiple processors access to the same data, we can use some primitives like lock or ATOMIC operations.

What if multiple processors write data on different location within the same cache-line? Do I need to use 'ATOMIC' operation to prevent any consistency issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This will not cause any consistency issues. The system takes care of it for you. It knows when to invalidate caches properly. But notice that if this occurs, it creates the "False Sharing" effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). If done too often, this can degrade performance significantly, because threads are waiting for the bus too many times, due to cache invalidation.

Explanation: Suppose that that A reads from a cache line, and then thread B write to the cache line. Now, next time that thread A reads from the same cache line, the CPU knows that the cache line is invalid, so it reads it again from RAM before thread A can continue. In this way, even though there is no race condition, thread A now works more slowly because of what thread B is doing

Comment: thanks Adi, this is interesting. Then why writing the data at the exactly same spot becomes an issue? Why CPU cannot hand both case in a same manner?

Comment: It's only a performance issue. Suppose that that A reads from a cache line, and then thread B write to the cache line. Now, next time that thread A reads from the same cache line, the CPU knows that the cache line is invalid, so it reads it again from RAM before thread A can continue. In this way, even though there is no race condition, thread A now works more slowly because of what thread B is doing.